# Guardar información SQLite desde Kotlin

Tags: sqlite, kotlin, android-fragment

Me podrían decir si tengo algún error, estoy tratando de guardar información en mi base de datos SQLite.

```
class CategoriesFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?

): View? {
```

Cita en bloque estoy mandando la información que me de el usuario por medio de mi función insertData

```
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categories,container, false)
    val context = view.context
    view.btnAgregar.setOnClickListener({
        if (txtNombre.text.toString().length > 0){
            var categories = Categories(txtNombre.text.toString())
            var db = DataBaseHandler(context)
            db.insertData(categories)
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(context,"Por Favor Complete El Campo Anterior",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

    })
    return view
    }
}
```

Nota: Estoy trabajando con kotlin

Comment: Acostumbra revisar el LogCat, ahì te da màs idea del error, que se muestra ahì?

Comment: Gracias por el consejo, pero tengo un error que cada vez que hago clic en el botón me lanza el mensaje de que mi app no responde. Alguna idea de por que pasa eso @Elenasys

Answer (score 0):

No has introducido la interfaz OnClickListener en la clase, tal vez por este motivo no responde tu aplicación al presionar el botón. Si no revisa el LogCat y consulta los errores.

> class CategoriesFragment : Fragment() {